# Okular - apt and snap cannot resize

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, qt, okular

I have been a long-time user of Okular, but after a recent fresh installation, I've noticed the absence of the maximize button.

My main issue is the inability to resize the windows, as I can only adjust them vertically. Moreover, every time I switch screens, I have to manually resize the window to fit the new screen.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Ubuntu 22.04
Okular snap version 23.08.4 and apt version
Plasma + GTK (Gnome)
PDF Backend Version 0.6.5

Comment: Which Ubuntu 22.04 are you on? Ubuntu GNOME or Kubuntu? The maximize button in the title bar is supposed to be drawn according to the desktop environment. If on Kubuntu, you can get back the title bar with Alt+F3 > More Actions > uncheck "No Border"

Comment: Thank you but I am on Ubuntu GNOME